# Тестирование покупок в Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, тестирование, google-play-console, android-billing

Заранее извиняюсь за глупый вопрос, но каким образом производится тестирование биллинга приложения в Android studio?
Как локально, в эмуляторе Android Studio получать список ограниченного контента в Google Play Console, дабы протестировать некоторые функциональные возможности?
Если локально нельзя, то тогда как? Написать код биллинга, загрузить приложение в Google Play Console, пройти модерацию, скачать его по внутреннему тестированию, понять что какое-то условие поставил не правильно и начать все заново? Звучит глупо, но других решений я найти не смог.
Для биллинга использую Google Play's billing.

Answer (score 0):

Может кому то поможет.
Тестирование можно проводить через Android устройство, подключенное к интернету. Подключаем устройство к рабочему компьютеру, в Android Studio выбираем это устройство и вуа-ля, получаем данные покупок с Google Play Console. Насколько я понял, через эмулятор это сделать не получится.

Comment: Через эмулятор тоже можно. Надо только чтобы там гугло-сервисы были.